# Adding Installation path into registry wix

Tags: wix

This is my wix installer command in order to create registry key for my software:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" 
                                             Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
```

How to create my installation path in the registry key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your directories are setup like this:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyProductName" />
```

If you want to store the installation path in registry you can use the value of that variable `INSTALLDIR` inside your `RegistryValue` element:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
  Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" 
  Type="string"
  Value="[INSTALLDIR]"
  KeyPath="yes"/>
```